# executeBatch() locks table when updating

Tags: java, prepared-statement, websphere-7

I am executing an update with preparedStatement and executebatch like this:

```
query = "UPDATE BP_PROCESO SET " +
                "FILTROS = FILTROS||?, " +
                "COD_ETAPA_RECHAZO= ?," +
                "APROBADO=? " +
                "WHERE " +
                "NIU=? AND " +
                "COD_CAMPANIA = ?";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);


Iterator it = registros.entrySet().iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){

         int contador = 1;
            ps.setObject(contador++, cadenaFiltro);
            ps.setObject(contador++, etapaRechazo);
            ps.setObject(contador++, 0);
            ps.setObject(contador++, pojo.getNiu());
            ps.setObject(contador++, codigoCampania);
            ps.addBatch();
            if(respuesta %500==0){
                System.out.println(respuesta);
                ps.executeBatch();
                System.out.println("executed");
                ps.clearBatch();
            }
 }
```

In the first time when ps.executeBatch() the table gets locked, however I am debugging in Apache Tomcat and it does not get locked, the application is installed in Websphere   7.0.0.17, I am getting the connection by JNDI

Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same transaction isolation level in both application servers?  If you aren't sure, you can check by invoking `con.getTransactionIsolation()` and comparing the value.  Most JDBC drivers have a default of `java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED` (2) whereas WebSphere Application Server uses a default of `java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ` (4) for most databases. The transaction isolation level impacts what locking is done in the database, with `TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ` typically involving more restrictive locking than `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED`.  To change the transaction isolation level programmatically, for example, you can do `con.setTransactionIsolation(java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITED)` after you obtain the connection.  Note that you can also override the default transaction isolation level at the data source level via the `webSphereDefaultIsolationLevel` data source custom property.  You can also configure a transaction isolation level on the resource reference extensions for the resource reference that you are using to obtain the data source.

The following tech note contains additional information on transaction isolation levels in WebSphere Application Server,

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1012999